# Truncate items in dropdrown menu and selected item using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, text, truncate

I have a dropdown menu populated from a django object. These items can be so much longer than the width of the dropdownmenu and don't want the width to change.

How can I limit it to display only the first 15 characters in the list and append ... after the 15th character?

I have the following in my template:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn-warning" href="{% url 'courses:course-detail' course.id %}" id="course-name-nav" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home pull-left"></span>{{course.name}}<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   {% for course in user|get_user_courses %}
     <li><a href="{% url 'courses:course-detail' course.id %}" id="course-list-item">{{course.name}}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</li>
```

and I added a jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var len = 15;
    $('#course-in-nav').change(function() {
       var text = $(this).text();
       console.log($(this).text());
       console.log($(this).text().length);
       if(text.length > len) {
          $(this).text() = text.substring(0, len) + '...';
      }
  });
</script>
```

How can I actually do that? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I used Sushil's solution, however, that only updated the items in the dropdown menu. I added same code to do the same thing to the selected item. However, this solution is overwriting my  and  elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.dropdown-menu').find('li').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    var length = $(link).text().length;
    if(length > 15){
        var truncated = $(link).text().substring(0, 15) + '...';
        $(link.text(truncated));
    }
});
});
$(function(){
$('.dropdown').find('a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    var length = text.length;
    if(length > 15){
        truncated = text.substring(0, 15) + '...';
        console.log(truncated);
        $($(this).text(truncated));
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/4262prrs/3/

Comment: Would a pure CSS solution that achieves the same goal be acceptable?

Comment: @Sushil it worked from the drop down menu but not when it shows the selected item. See my edit above, the issue now that it seems to overwrite <span> and <b> elements?

Comment: can you update the fiddle and add the generated dropdown so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the angular filter 'limitTo' to truncate the strings.  See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need javascript. You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` along with `overflow: hidden` on any block level element with a width set. It will truncate any text that won't fit within the width and add ... For example:

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;/* this can be any width you want */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```